# Detecting if input has been entered before

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Lately I've been having trouble checking whether an input (player name) has been input more than once. This is not in-database, but just based on arrays contained within JavaScript. What I've been using after a couple of google searches was the indexOf() function. However this does not seem to work. My code is as follows:

```
var numberPlayers = 1;
var players = [];

var AddPlayer = function() {
    if(!(players.indexOf($(".name")).val() > -1)) {
        players.push($(".name").val());

        $(".players").append("<p>Player number " + numberPlayers + " is " + $(".name").val() + "</p>");
        numberPlayers++;
    }
};
```

What method of detection would you recommend? I've tried looping, but wouldn't work either.

EDIT: Updated code. Still doesn't work!

Comment: This syntax, what is it supposed to do? `$".name"`

Comment: You can add specific class to your input for the first time and each time that user focus on the input, You can check if the input has that class or not.

Comment: @JaredFarrish That is jQuery, a JavaScript framework. Edit: I'm sorry! I see the error now!

Comment: @Herbstein `$` is the jQuery function, but `$".name"` is not valid JavaScript.  Please verify that you copied and pasted the code correctly.

Comment: @Herbstein `$".name"` is wrong, you should pass ".name" as a parameter to `$`, like this : `$(".name")

Comment: I know what jQuery is (see my answer history). I believe you mean `$(".name")`. Also, I believe you want to look for `!== -1`, which means it was not found. Right now you're only finding matches. (jQuery is also a library, not a framework; Ember.js is a framework.)

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Can you give me an example? The input is coming from an input of type text, submitted by an input of type button and appended to a ul. I have just added <li></li> to the above code.

Comment: Actually, now I see the negation on the `indexOf()` check. This should be removed and checked directly; the unreadability of doing a negation on something that can be checked directly is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object (read Set / Hash) instead of an array; it should be faster anyway.
Note that I'm also using .text() which will escape text.

```
var numberPlayers = 1;
var players = {};
var AddPlayer = function() {
    var newPlayer = $(".name").val();
    if(!(newPlayer in players)) {
        players[newPlayer] = true;
        $(".players").append($("<p>").text("Player number " + numberPlayers + " is " + newPlayer));
        numberPlayers++;
    }
};
```

Comment: That might be the most elegant solution to my problem yet. I did get a working function up and running, but this looks and feels much better! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this - note where the `)` is placed:

```
if(!(players.indexOf($(".name").val()) > -1)) {
```

instead of:

```
if(!(players.indexOf($(".name")).val() > -1)) {
```

and actually, for readability this would be better:

```
var name = $('.name').val();
if ( players.indexOf(name) == -1)) {
```

In general, try adding `console.log` and breakpoints to find your bugs...

Comment: Thank you! I somehow didn't notice the missing `)` in-between switching statements and trying different methods.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery has a utility function](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray) for this:

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```

It returns the index of a value in an array. It returns -1 if the array does not contain the value.